# great circle distance c++

Tags: c++, distance, direction, great-circle

I've included code (now) for the great circle distance formula. Code works until one of the lats/longs has S/E attached as their respective directions ( I attempted to use S/E as "negative directions"). Any help is extremely appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "lat.hpp"
#include <string>

#define PI 3.14159265


double greatCircleDistance(double lat1, double long1, char latDir1 ,
                            char longDir1, double lat2, double long2,
                            char latDir2, char longDir2)
  {
  double dLat;
  double dLong;

   latDirectionCheck(latDir1, lat1);
   latDirectionCheck(latDir2, lat2);
   longDirectionCheck(longDir1, long1);
   longDirectionCheck(longDir2, long2);

   dLat = (lat1 - lat2) ;
   dLong = (long1 - long2);

   positivify(dLat);
   positivify(dLong);
   positivify(lat1);
   positivify(lat2);

    //convert all numbers to Rad
    dLat = convertRadians(dLat);
    dLong = convertRadians(dLong);
    lat1 = convertRadians(lat1);
    lat2 = convertRadians(lat2);

    double R = 3959.9;
    double num1 = sin(dLat/2);
    double num2 = sin(dLong/2);



    double a = pow(num1,2) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) *
               pow(num2,2);
    double c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a));
    double d = R * c;
    return d;
   }

 double latDirectionCheck(char check, double convert) {
     if(check == 'S') 
      convert = -convert;
      return convert;
 }

 double longDirectionCheck(char check, double convert) {
    if(check == 'E')
       convert = -convert;
       return convert;
    }

 double positivify(double num) {
    if (num < 0) 
    num = num*(-1);
    return num;
 }

 bool compareFarDistance(double num1, double num2) {
    bool statement = false;
    if(num1 > num2)
        statement = true;
        return statement; 
 }

 bool compareCloseDistance(double num1, double num2) {
    bool statement = false;
    if(num1 < num2)
        statement = true;
        return statement;
 }
 double convertRadians(double num) {
   num = PI*(num/180);
   return num;
 }

 double convertDegrees(double num) {
    num = 180 * (num/PI);
    return num;

 }
```

Input: `23.4356/S 46.4731/W`

Distance Output: `4335.48`

Comment: Please post a minimal example

Comment: Can you describe more an example input/output which doesn't work? e.g., how you do know it doesn't work?

Comment: `positivify` does basically the same as `fabs` or floating point absolute value. Make sure you use standard library functions when possible

Answer (score 1):

You don't use the return values of the various direction check functions or the positivify function and they take their parameters by value. So they have no effect. You either need to pass them parameters by reference or use their return values. Otherwise, they compute a value and return it to code that ignores it.

Comment: After referencing the return values in the code                    (dLat = latDirectionCheck(latDir1, lat1) , I still seem to be getting the same answer? Am I missing more?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I got it working! Thank you so much. I can't believe I over looked linking the updated dLat to the return value. As for the pow function with trigonometric functions, I did this band-aidish move just because this is relatively my first major c++ program, and I was unsure how to use exponents. The answer below linking to Vincenty doesn't make sense and I'd rather not implement formulas I have little to no understanding about. But again, thank you for pointing out my answer! You're a life saver David!

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the programming errors (see @David Schwartz), your approach is deficient in that you will lose too much precision; especially when the end points are proximate. (Very simply, mixing `pow` with trigonometric functions is a recipe for excessive precision loss in floating point).

You ought to use Vincenty instead. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae.

And use M_PI if your compiler supports it, or define PI to the limit of double precision.